# Toggling icon images using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have about 5 of these but I can't figure out how to consolidate them.

```
$('#togglemass').toggle(function () {
    $("#plusmass").attr("src", "minus.png");
  },

  function () {
    $(".plusmass").attr("src", "plus.png");

  });


$('#togglestar').toggle(function () {
    $(".plusstar").attr("src", "minus.png");
  },

  function () {
    $(".plusstar").attr("src", "plus.png");
  });
```

Comment: You should explain your use case and show the HTML to this, because I think the optimization could start on the HTML level. For example, I think you should't need to hard code the selector to the "plus" image in the JavaScript, but refer to it via the HTML structure.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {

    var togglePlusMin = function(clicker, img) {
        $(clicker).toggle(function() {
            $(img).attr("src", "minus.png");
        }, function() {
            $(img).attr("src", "plus.png");
        });
    };

    // can be used by
    togglePlusMin('#togglemass', '#plusmass');      

    // BONUS: this will also work:
    var star = $('#togglestar'),
        starIcon = $('img.plusstar');

    togglePlusMin(star, starIcon);
})
```

As a comment, its generally a bad idea to use ids without [a second context parameter](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/)

Comment: I have the worst luck, this is the 2nd time in a week someone beat me to an answer by a few seconds.